# Need to change background image onmouseover in a jquery site

Tags: jquery, css, hover, background-image, onmouseover

hecked up trying a onmouseover background image change event for a link in a jquery site, if anyone knows it, please answer this with a demo!

Comment: Why you need jQuery, this can be done using pure css? Or isn't it the link itself whose bg you like to change?

Answer (score 5):

**Assumption**: you have a transparent background image like the one in this example.

Working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/Bytmn/

```
$('#logo').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
});
```

You'll need an image with `logo` id and a CSS rule for the `highlighted` class.

[jQuery `hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover) expects two functions to be called:

1. One mouse is over (`mouseenter` event)
2. One mouse is out (`mouseleave` event)

Answer (score 2):

```
a
{
background:#ffffff url('path-of-your-mouseout-image.jpg') no-repeat top left;
}

a:hover
{
background:#ffffff url('path-of-your-mouseover-image.jpg') no-repeat top left;
}
```

CSS CAN DO IT BUDDY.

Comment: Please dont forget to mark an answer as correct by clicking the tick mark on the left @johnsaxon